# Installing JavaCV and OpenCV using on ubuntu (for eclipse)

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I am trying to install OpenCV and JavaCV on ubuntu 12.04. I have gone through this link [here](http://codeadapter.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-detect-features-objects-face-eye.html). I have following queries.

1. Can I just use OpenCV zip instead of running and installing exe.
2. This link says https://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/list, javacv code is depricated. From where I can find javaCV code?

Comment: just as a sidenote, opencv comes with its own java wrappers since some time already. you might be better off using those instead of the old, deprecated c-api wrappers in javacv.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question: Follow the [Installation in Linux](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation) instructions on the OpenCV page. I setup OpenCV on Ubuntu 12.04 and later on 14.04 following these instructions and it helped me perfectly.

To your second question: I don't know javacv, but if it says it's deprecated, you probably shouldn't use it ;) OpenCV supports Java bindings since version 2.4.4, so you won't need javacv. I think you can do everything with Java-OpenCV you need. For information about Java development with OpenCV, see [Introduction to Java Development](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html#java-dev-intro). As far as I remember, Java bindings are created by default when building.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

From [javacv](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/):

The main project site of JavaCV has moved to GitHub! This site on Google Code is no longer maintained. Please find up-to-date information over there:

(https://github.com/bytedeco)

From [bytedeco/javacv](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv):

Downloads

To install manually the JAR files, obtain the following archives and follow the instructions in the Manual Installation section below.

...

Manual Installation for OpenCV and FFmpeg

Simply put all the JAR files of JavaCPP, JavaCV, OpenCV, and FFmpeg (javacpp.jar, javacv.jar, opencv-*.jar, and ffmpeg-*.jar, respectively) somewhere in your CLASSPATH. Here are some more specific instructions for common cases: ...